# What is the appropriate way to do an entity count endpoint in a rest controller

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a crud resource implemented by a springboot rest controller, with get, post, put and delete methods. I'd like to know the appropriate way to fetch the entity count, do i use the get method ("/") passing some header/parameter or do i create an new expecific end point like ("/count")?

```
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/modules")
public class ModuleResource {

    private final ModuleService service;

    @GetMapping("/count")
    public Long count() {
        return service.countModules();
    }


    @GetMapping
    public List<Module> find( 
                @RequestParam("name") String name ,
                @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
                @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "10") Integer size
    ) {
        log.info("searching module by name {} " , name);
        return service.find(Module.builder().name(name).build(), PageRequest.of(page, size));
    }
}
```

Comment: My preferred way is a complex find where you get the number of all resources together with the currently requested "page" - either in a single JSON reponse (body) or as response header fields. But besides that, totally opinionated.

Answer (score 1):

Two things

First, the count endpoint is not a bad solution IMO if you don't want to expose all your data.

Secondly, just an advice, the second endpoint can be simplified using Spring MVC Pageable implement. If your data is store in a database fetched by Spring Data, you can simply do

```java
@GetMapping
public Page<Module> find(@RequestParam("name") String name, Pageable pageable) {
    log.info("searching module by name {} " , name);
    return service.find(Module.builder().name(name).build(), pageable);
}
```

And then send the Pageable object to the Spring Data Repository to get a `Page<Module>` of results.

```java
public class MyRepository extends CrudRepository<Module, String> {
    public Page<Module> findAllByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```